# OpenMDAO v1.x feature request: finite difference method option in derivative check methods

Tags: openmdao

We have found that several components of our code fail the gradient check when using forward or backward differencing, but pass when using the more accurate central differencing. To remedy this we have modified the default in these functions in our version of the code to use central differencing.

We would like to request that the finite differencing method used by the derivative check methods be made an option so that the tests can pass when run by other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should already be able to do this on an individual variable basis by specifying the `form` in the `add_param` for the variables you want to central difference.

```
self.add_param('x2', 3.0, form = 'central')
```

Alternatively, you can set them for all params in a single component by:

```
self.fd_options['form'] = 'central'
```

The `check_partial_derivatives` will definitely pick this up. Ultimately `check_total_derivatives` should also pick it up, but there is still an outstanding bug about what happens when you specify different values in multiple targets that are connected to a single IndepVarComp source -- which one does it use -- it uses the first one it finds right now.

You can also set `step_type` and `step_size` this way.

Comment: If the components provide gradients, and we are just using finite differencing to check them, will setting these options still allow the component to use the provided gradients during normal runs?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand how to use these, but when I try to call `self.fd_options['form'] = 'central'` in `def __init__(self):` within a component, I get an attribute error: `AttributeError: 'floris_wcent_wdiam' object has no attribute 'fd_options'`. :

Comment: It should be okay to keep these options in the variable metadata even when using analytic derivatives. Finite difference is only triggered by setting `force_fd` to True in a Component or Group.

Comment: Also, did you set the fd_option after calling `super` to call the base classes' constructors?

Comment: Thanks for asking, I had accidentally placed the fd_option calls prior to the call to super. It is working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Although you can control behavior on an individual variable level via meta-data, or a whole component level via FD options, its also reasonable to set specific options via kwargs to check_partial_derivs. This is something we can work on, though it won't be super high priority for us at the moment.